# How to write custom validate function react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form

I try use validate function on react-hook-form. I have two component :

```
<FormRow label="Giriş düzgüni" isEditor error={errors?.withTestFile?.message}> 
                <Controller 
                    name="withTestFile"
                    control={control}
                    render={ ({field})=>(
                        <Radio.Group 
                        buttonStyle="solid"
                        defaultValue={watch("withTestFile")}
                        {...field} 
                        >
                            <Radio.Button value={true}>Faýl arkaly</Radio.Button>
                            <Radio.Button value={false}>
                                Standart
                            </Radio.Button>
                        </Radio.Group>
                    ) }
                /> 
            </FormRow>           
            <FormRow label="Giriş faýlynyň ady" error={errors?.testFileInput?.message}>
                <Controller
                    name="testFileInput"
                    control={control}
                    rules={{ 
                        validate: (value)=> {
                            return (getValues().withTestFile === true  && (`${value || ''}`?.length ===0) ) && 'Giriş faýlyny giriziň' 
                        }    
                    }}
                    render={({ field }) => <Input {...field} disabled={!watch("withTestFile")} />}
                />
            </FormRow>
```

How write correct validation function? Idea this: if first one be true second one must be length > 0